# 2 files with same data being computed the same way producing different output

Tags: c++, file, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Firstly, I apologise for the vague question but I am at my wits end. I have made a compiler than converts Assembly code into Binary.

I am doing the NandToTetris course for making an assembler.

I have two files called "test.asm" and "MaxL.asm" that both have the same information in them:

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/06/max/MaxL.asm

// Symbol-less version of the Max.asm program.

@0
D=AMD
@1
D=D-M
@10
D;JGT
@1
D=M
@12
0;JMP
@0
D=M
@2
M=D
@14
0;JMP
```

When I call my program, a .hack extended file is generated (eg. test.hack)

When I call my program, MaxL.hack and test.hack should have the same output, however they don't!

Basically if I create the .asm file myself, the .hack that's created is perfect, however if I use any of the courses .asm files, it doesn't work, even if whats inside them is identical

Any point in the right direction would be incredibly appreciated.

Here is my code for context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int tempVarInst;
int tempVarDest;
int tempVarJmp = 0;


bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

bool isComment(string line){
    string comment = "/";
    if((line.find(comment)) != string::npos){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

string ConvertToBinary(unsigned int val)
{

    string tempStore;

   unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof(int) * 4 - 1);

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 4; i++)
   {
      if( (val & mask) == 0 )
         tempStore+='0';
      else
         tempStore+='1';


      mask  >>= 1;
   }
   return tempStore;
}

bool isMemLoc(string line){
    string symbol = "@";
    if(line.find(symbol) != string::npos ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}


int destConstants(string line){

    if(line== "A")
        return 2;
    if(line== "M")
        return 8;
    if(line== "D")
        return 16;
    if(line== "AM")
        return 40;
    if(line== "AD")
        return 48;
    if(line== "MD")
        return 24;
    if(line== "AMD")
        return 56;  
}

int isInst(string line){

    if(line=="0")
        return 60032;
    if(line=="1")
        return 61376;
    if(line=="-1")
        return 61056;
    if(line=="D")
        return 58112;
    if(line=="!D")
        return 58176;
    if(line=="M")
        return 64512;
    if(line=="A")
        return 60416;
    if(line=="!M")
        return 64576;
    if(line=="!A")
        return 60480;
    if(line=="-D")
        return 58304;
    if(line=="-M")
        return 64704;
    if(line=="-A")
        return 60608;
    if(line=="D+1")
        return 59328;
    if(line== "M+1")
        return 64960;
    if(line== "A+1")
        return 60864;
    if(line== "D-1")
        return 58240;
    if(line== "M-1")
        return 64640;
    if(line== "A-1")
        return 60544;
    if(line== "D+M")
        return 61568;
    if(line== "D+A")
        return 57472;
    if(line== "D-M")
        return 62656;
    if(line== "D-A")
        return 58560;
    if(line== "M-D")
        return 61888;
    if(line== "A-D")
        return 57792;
    if(line== "D&M")
        return 61440;
    if(line== "D&A")
        return 57344;
    if(line== "D|M")
        return 62784;
    if(line== "D|A")
        return 58688;   
}


int jmpConstants(string line){

    if(line== "JGT")
        return 1;
    if(line== "JEQ")
        return 2;
    if(line== "JGE")
        return 3;
    if(line== "JLT")
        return 4;
    if(line== "JNE")
        return 5;
    if(line== "JLE")
        return 6;
    if(line== "JMP")
        return 7;
}

bool isJumpInstruction(string line){

    string symbol = ";";
    if(line.find(symbol) != string::npos ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    string outLine = "testa output";
    string file1 = argv[1];
    replace(file1, "asm", "hack");

    //input
    //WHILE READ LINE()
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    string tempLine;

    ofstream outfile(file1.c_str());
    tempVarJmp=0;
    tempVarDest=0;
    tempVarInst=0;
    while (getline(infile, tempLine)){
        //Blank check
        cout << "The tempLine is: " << tempLine << endl;
        if(tempLine.length()<=1){
            continue;
        }
        //Comment Check
        else if(isComment(tempLine))
            continue;
        //@ Check
        else if(isMemLoc(tempLine)){
            tempLine.erase(0,1);
            int number = (atoi(tempLine.c_str()));
            cout << ConvertToBinary(number) << endl;
            outfile << ConvertToBinary(number) << std::endl;
            continue;
            }

            //tempLine=tempLine(isInst).c_str+tempLine(destConstants)+tempLine(jmpConstants);
            //outfile << ConvertToBinary(tempLine) << endl;

        else if(isJumpInstruction(tempLine)){

                cout << "Jump Instruction" << endl;
                tempVarJmp = jmpConstants(tempLine.substr(tempLine.find(';')+1));
                cout << "TempVarInst: " << tempLine.substr(tempLine.find(';')+1) << endl;
                cout << "tempVarJmp: " << tempVarJmp << endl;
                tempVarDest = isInst(tempLine.substr(0,tempLine.find(';')));
                cout << "tempvarDest = " << tempVarDest << endl;

                int finalVal=tempVarDest+tempVarJmp;
                outfile << ConvertToBinary(finalVal) << std::endl;
                cout << ConvertToBinary(finalVal) << endl;
            }else{

                cout << "Right TempLineInst is: " << tempLine.substr(tempLine.find('=')+1,tempLine.length()) << endl;
                cout << "Right TempLineDest is: " << tempLine.substr(0,tempLine.find('=')) << endl;

                tempVarInst = isInst(tempLine.substr(tempLine.find('=')+1,tempLine.length()));
                tempVarDest = destConstants(tempLine.substr(0,tempLine.find('=')));
                tempVarJmp = 0;
                if(tempLine.substr(1,2) == ";J"){
                    tempVarJmp = jmpConstants(tempLine.substr(2,4));
                    cout << "TempLineDest is: " << tempLine.substr(2,4) << endl;

                }
                cout << "tempvarInst = " << tempVarInst << endl;
                cout << "tempvarDest = " << tempVarDest << endl;
                cout << "tempvarJmp = " << tempVarJmp << endl;
                int totalSum = tempVarInst+tempVarDest+tempVarJmp;
                cout << "totalSum: " << ConvertToBinary(totalSum) << endl;

                outfile << ConvertToBinary(totalSum) << std::endl;
            }


        //print to terminal and pass to file
        //outfile << tempLine << std::endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
    //BINARY CONVERSION, feed conversion into 'line' variable
    //output
}
```

Here is the (correct) input using test.asm in test.hack

```
0000000000000000
1111111100010000
0000000000000001
1111010011010000
0000000000001010
1110001100000001
0000000000000001
1111110000010000
0000000000001100
1110101010000111
0000000000000000
1111110000010000
0000000000000010
1110001100001000
0000000000001110
1110101010000111
```

now for (incorrect) MaxL.hack code

```
0000000000000000
1111111100010000
0000000000000001
1111111100010000
0000000000001010
1110001000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000010000
0000000000001100
1110101010000000
0000000000000000
0000000000010000
0000000000000010
1111111100001000
0000000000001110
1110101010000000
```

if you change MaxL.asm's name, it's still produces incorrect info, and if you change 'test.asm's' name, it still produces correct info

Comment: Are you sure you're input files are identical? try copying 1 of them to a new name and see how that goes

Comment: hey Amit, they are identical, I copy and pasted the input from one to another and they still produce different output

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?  What's wrong with the incorrect output?  I'm not convinced both input files are identical.  What happens if you just rename the correct file or make a copy of the file using the file system and not copy/paste that could switch encoding or line endings?

Comment: I will add all of that info now Retired Ninja, thanks!

Comment: Do both files have the same line endings? Did you binary compare the two files and found no differences?

Comment: Hey Axxis how do I perform this

Comment: `fc /b file1 file2` in a Windows command prompt will compare the files.

Comment: I am currently on redhat linux. Do you know of a bash command?

Comment: Use the `cmp` command. `cmp file1 file2`

Comment: When I run your program with your input file I get the correct result. The result doesn't depend on the file name.